# Expectation of matrix X multiply by indicator matrix

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Let X1, . . . , Xn, X be i.i.d. R-valued random variables

[image]

Suppose an indicator matrix I{A} be 1 if A is true and 0 otherwise. Then for τ > 0,

[image]

and

[image]

How this could be true....? Can anyone walk through above statement? I think it only needs 2-3 steps but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by an "indicator *matrix*"?  You seem to be using this as if it were an indicator *function.*

Comment: Oops sorry, yes , indicator function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via some algebraic tricks, we have:

For the first one, 
$$\begin{align}E[X^2\mathcal{I}(|X|<\tau)] &=\int_{-\tau}^\tau{|x|^2 f(x)dx}=\int_{-\tau}^\tau |x|^{1-b} |x|^{1+b}f(x)dx\\ &\leq\tau^{1-b}\int_{-\tau}^\tau|x|^{1+b}f(x)dx\leq \tau^{1-b}E[|X|^{1+b}]\leq a\tau^{1-b}\end{align}$$

For the second one,
$$\begin{align}|E[X\mathcal{I}(X>\tau)]| &\leq E[|X|\mathcal{I}(X>\tau)] =\int_\tau^\infty|x|f(x)dx \\ &= \int_\tau^\infty|x|^{1+b}|x|^{-b}f(x)dx\\ &\leq \tau^{-b}\int_{\tau}^{\infty}|x|^{1+b}f(x)dx\leq\tau^{-b}E[|X|^{1+b}]\\ &\leq a\tau^{-b}\end{align}$$